# Should I reload the whole component after a Post Request?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a simple list component that show all the records. When it mounts, it call GET to get all the records from the DB then store it in the state.

There's also a dialog that i can use to add a record. After i add a record, there're two ways to update the list:

1. Call GET again and reload the whole list.
2. Push the new record obj into the component state.

Which approach should i take?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the project, I would most often prefer approach number 2 since it results in the best user experience.

Approach 2 saves the client from making an unnecessary request. Approach 2 will result in quicker feedback to the user after the add record request.